# bash: !": event not found in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: linux, bash

I am facing the following error

```
bash: !": event not found
```

while i have write the following command

```
echo "HI"  test.txt
```

in terminal,

whats the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably typing it as:

```
echo "HI!" >> test.txt
```

**!** is a special character in bash (Linux) and needs to be escaped like so:

```
echo "HI\!" >> test.txt
```

I think this question is answered very well in this link: https://serverfault.com/questions/208265/what-is-bash-event-not-found?newreg=2077048244ee45dbb6f7d1925d71458f

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is not what he is typing. There is no ! in his command.

Comment: the command typed in this question might not be the whole code. Sometimes we suspect code in some other location when it actually happens else where.

Comment: You are right, but in this case you are assuming that his entering "HI!" and clearly this is not what he is typing.

Comment: he might update his question any time soon, lets wait and watch :)

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your command, You need to add the '>>' between your text and your name file and also try removing the quotes:

```
echo HI >> test.txt
```

Comment: Theres no difference.

Comment: in fact there is no different whether i use >> or not @S.Pinkus

Comment: @Rego did you try removing the quotes?